# Ignore fdescribe in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

One of the developers on our team (me) keeps accidentally checking in `fdescribe` and `fit` in Jasmine tests. Which sometimes results in masking broken tests.

Is there an easy way to either fail a build (TFS) if `fdescribe` is used, or (better?) configure jasmine server side to treat `fdescribe` (and `fit`) as regular `describe` (and `it`)?

I would rather use those then fall back to `?spec` approach.

I also would like to take this opportunity to apologize for doing that.

Comment: Has the answer eventually helped? What option have you went with? Thanks.

Comment: I added code to our common test file bootstrap, and emit a large "fdescribe has been used" text to the top of the test runner page, hoping that will remind a developer to turn focus off.

Answer (score 4):

We've approached it with static code analysis and [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/).

There is a specific plugin: [`eslint-plugin-jasmine`](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine), see:

- [Disallow use of focused tests (no-focused-tests)](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine/blob/master/docs/rules/no-focused-tests.md#disallow-use-of-focused-tests-no-focused-tests)

Sample output:

```
test/e2e/specs/test.spec.js
  5:0  error  Unexpected fdescribe  jasmine/no-focused-tests
```

Currently, the plugin also checks for disabled tests and duplicate suite names.

Comment: Here is also a module for gulp: [gulp-ddescribe-iit](https://github.com/caitp/gulp-ddescribe-iit)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to make `fit` and `fdescribe` behave like `it` and `describe` respectively, you can override one with the other in a separate file and insert it before your actual specs (how to insert depends on your test runner):

```
// assuming Jasmine is already loaded and has published it's public API
fit = it;
fdescribe = describe;
```

But I would not suggest to use this approach, because if you really want to focus some spec, you'd have to comment these things or exclude the file from a runner. I would rather add this as another step for the build process, if you have one, or pre-commit hook, which would run some tool, like [@alecxe has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31729323/1573638), analyzing the code for existing `fit` and `fdescribe` and fail a build / reject a commit.